# Cannot find Power Pack under Tools in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, printing, powerpacks

I downloaded `Powerpack 10.0` from the web and installed on my development Machine. I restarted VS2012. When I go to .NET Components I can see `Printform` being checked however it doesn't show up under Toolbox.

Edited---
Well if I select "show all" under "ToolBox" it shows "Printing" control. But the components inside "Printing" is all disabled. How do I make it enabled? I am using 4.5 Framework with VS2012.

Thanks.

Comment: What is powerpack 10.0?

Comment: It is Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks vs, version 10.0. I think it is the same as 3.0, thats what I read. The download link says 3.0

Comment: 2 things, what framework are you using (Winforms, WPF, ASP.net) and what is the link that you used to download the PowerPack ?

Comment: @MarkHall - ASP.NET framework. I downloaded from this link:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169. Then I read Powerpack was incorporated with 2012. I think I had the component before I downloaded it. I have express edition though.

Comment: @Nita the reason that it is grayed out is that the powerpack is essentially adding functionality that was available in VB6 to winforms. Since your project is ASP.Net they are not available. Since I do not program ASP.net I am not sure wether or not they will even function correctly, I think you will have security/permission issues.

Comment: @Mark Hall - Thank you. I will forget about this feature for now.